# EFS 'sudo mount -t nfs4' hangs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I've created an EFS volume with Amazon. I then open up port 1194 for incoming UDP connections on the server I want to mount EFS to.

I ssh into the server and then run the command suggested by Amazon:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 fs-ff22f056.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/ efs
```

After running the command it just seems to hang with no success or error message.

*My ec2 instance has an area of us-west-2c, which is listed as one of 3 available zones on my EFS instance.*

Answer (score 2):

> I then open up port 1194 for incoming UDP connections on the server I want to mount EFS to.

UDP port 1194 is the IANA assigned port for OpenVPN, so it's not clear how you concluded this would be needed.

EFS uses only TCP port 2049.  The security group associated with the EFS filesystem's mount target needs to allow access from your instance to TCP/2049.

Your instance needs to allow the traffic outbound, which it will by default unless you have changed the default outbound on the instance's security groups, or you've changed the default network ACLs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/security-considerations.html